# Problems with "Discount Full Graphic Smart Controller"!

Tags: reprap, lcd-screen, full-graphic-smart-controller

I bought a new "RepRap Discount Full Graphic Smart Controller" for my printer. I'm having a hard time installing it. LCD wouldn't turn on and a ticking noise was getting out of the buzzer. It turned out that some have inverted sockets! So I scratched them to be used inverted. LCD turned on, rotary encoder, reset button, SD card and potentiometer and everything work but I get a quite scrambled show on LCD as it's shown in the picture.
I tried every possible combination of sockets (inverted and not) I don't know what is wrong!!!

[image]

Comment: The content of your display is so close to the expected picture, that I would not suspect signal incompatibility or any internal issues related to shift register, etc. - but I don't know details of I2C. I was happy to make old Panelolu v1 working with Marlin 2, but it's easier to debug when each pin goes straight to Arduino. I don't know how to approach. Also you should consider that it could be provided broken or you could burn something as well with inverted plug. Did you try [any troubleshooting guide](https://www.instructables.com/Reprap-Full-Graphic-Smart-Discount-Controller/)?

Comment: I'm confused. That troubleshooting link didn't help.